# How to add data to the end of a line in text file in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, codeblocks

I am a beginner in C++ programming. I need to create a program for a movie reservation system. I have done it until halfway through, but I am stuck at selecting the seats. I need to program it like the user must select a seat. The user can select seats for about 10 times in a loop. After selecting it, all the data should be stored in the text file, and in the line which I have stored the information about the particular movie. I am really hoping for a good suggestion to this problem. This is how I arrange the text file:

```
Avengers|1600|40|16
LoST World|3200|40|16
Titanic|6897|87|16
Avengers|1600|40|16
```

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

display_all()
{
    char name [25];
    char hours[25];
    char seats[25];

    fstream movie;
    movie.open("Movies.txt",ios::in);

    int count = 0;
    string line;

    ifstream file("Movies.txt");
    while (getline(file, line))
        count++;

    int i = 0;
    while(!movie.eof(), i++ , i<= count)
    {
        movie.getline(name,25,'|');
        movie.getline(seats,25,'|');
        movie.getline(hours,25);
        cout<< "(" << i << ") " <<  name << "\n                   ";
    }
    return 0;
}

main()
{
    char name [25];
    char hours[25];
    char seats[25];
    char price[25];
    char seats1[25];
    char seats2[25];
    char seats3[25];
    char seats4[25];
    char seats5[25];

    char response = 'Y';
    string customer, phone_number;
    fstream movie;
    movie.open("Movies.txt",ios::in);
    char selection_role ;
    int selection_movie ;

    cout << "                  *************************************************************** " << endl;
    cout << "                              MOVIE TICKET RESERVATION SYSTEM (MTRS)              " << endl;
    cout << "                  *************************************************************** " << endl;
    cout << endl << endl ;
    cout << "                           Please specify the selection : (1) CUSTOMER"   << endl;
    cout << "                                                          (2) MANAGEMENT" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "                                           INPUT : ";
    cin >> selection_role;

    if (selection_role == 1);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "MOVIES AVAILABLE : ";
    display_all();

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please select a movie: ";
    cin >> selection_movie ;

    int i = 0;
    while(i++ , i <= selection_movie)
    {
      movie.getline(name,25,'|');
      movie.getline(seats,25,'|');
      movie.getline(hours,25,'|');
      movie.getline(price,25,'|');
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "======You have selected " << name <<".=========" <<endl;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Movie hours: " << seats << endl;
    cout << "Number of seats available: " << hours << endl;
    cout << "                                  SCREEN                                      "<<endl << endl;
    cout << "1         2          3          4          5          6          7          8" <<endl << endl;
    cout << "9         10         11         12         13         14         15         16"<<endl << endl;
    cout << "17        18         19         20         21         22         23         24"<<endl << endl;;
    cout << "25        26         27         28         29         30         31         32"<<endl << endl;

    cout << "Enter the number of seat you would like to book for: ";
    cin >> seats1 ;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Price for the ticket: RM " << price <<  endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter you name: " ;
    cin >> customer ;
    cout << "Enter your phone number: ";
    cin >> phone_number;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "         MOVIE TICKET       " << endl;
    cout << "============================" << endl;
    cout << "Name                   :" << customer << endl;
    cout << "Handphone number       :" << phone_number <<endl;
    cout << "Movie selected         :" << name << endl;
    cout << "Seat selected          :" << seats1 <<"," << seats2 << endl;
    cout << "Price for the movie(RM):" << price << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you use a C++ compiler you have to specify a return type for your functions.

Comment: `while(!movie.eof(), i++, i<= count)`- that is a very unusual loop. You can get rid of the 2nd `fstream` and just use a single `while(getline)` loop. You don’t need the `count` variable at all. Also, `if (selection_role == 1);` is a no-op that can be removed. And `while(i++, i <= selection_movie)` should be written as a `for` loop instead.

Comment: What happens when `selection_role == 1`?

Comment: Remy Lebeau can you help me get things done. I would really appreciate that since this is my first time learning this c++ your guidance would help me to understand how to get things done.

Comment: Rohan Bari.. I havent completed the coding yet because section 1 is for customer and section 2 is for management where management can edit the movies in the file

Comment: The if statement should be "if (selection_role == '1') (note the single quotes) and instead of ";" there should be braces following it that contain all the logic that follows, followed by an else {<manager logic>}